# IIS aborts request thread with Win32 status 995

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

We have a site where we have trouble on our production server, but not on my dev machine with request beeing aborted (hence, zero response).

It fails after exactly 1:19 minutes each time, and the request on my dev machine takes approx 1:44.

The content length is about 650K so that shouldn't be a problem.

The production enviroment is windows 2008 with IIS7
the dev enviroment is windows 7 with IIS 7.5

The have identical web.config but the machine config differs slightly (although they should be standard from install)

What could be causing this?

When looking in the access-log, the row says 0 byte in response byt win32-code 995 which should be 0
this is the last columns from the access-row:

```
sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes time-taken
200       0            995             0        76933
```

995 seems to be related to "thread aborted" or something, hence I'm kind of confident that it's IIS that aborts the request. the w3wp.exe process seems to run for some time even after the request stopped, so I don't think the web application even notices until it's time to write to the output stream.

EDIT: Have tried now with different connections and it seems like my firewall drops the connection because of no data (prematurely). Hence the 995 code.

Comment: The default "minBytesPerSecond" is 240, which would result in 46 minutes, but you might see some dynamically adjusted timeouts instead (IIS does that based on dynamicIdleThreshold if not 0).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, in my case the Network Adapter is the cause of the sc-win32-status 995.
What did you change in the Firewall to  prevent this?
In device manager => network adapter => properties => advanced you can set several network related settings

Comment: Our firewall had a ALG for HTTP configured, which would cut the connection after 120 seconds if no data would flow through it. I just disabled it for the IP in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the "executionTimeout" setting in ASP.NET. The default for that seems to be 110 seconds which is similar to what you're reporting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

This could be present any of these configs:

- Machine.config
- Root-level Web.config
- Application-level Web.config
- Virtual or physical directory–level Web.config

Hope this helps.