# sc-win32-status 995 and TCP RST on HTTP GET (IIS 8.5)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, web-hosting, iis-8.5

I'm running a custom PHP/HTML application on Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5 on my company local intranet (server and clients are at the same location, no VPN, or whatever, only a gateway between VLANs). This site/application can host different files type and offers them to HTTP download.

On HTTP GET request (in order to download these files on client) we randomly gets some sc-win32-status 995, and the download fails:

```
2017-11-03 06:27:54 10.214.72.26 GET /tpm/lecon/fichiers/LP-2859.docx - 80 - 10.214.77.6 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64;+rv:56.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/56.0 http://amtblieapp1.xxx.xxx/tpm/lecon/afficher.php?id=2859&aLire=oui 206 0 995 18951
```

After a few page refresh it sometimes works for the same file.

It seems that the server resets the connection immediatly after the GET request, see this wireshark dump from the client (Client : 10.214.77.16; Server : 10.214.72.26):

```
41  5.466337    10.214.77.16    10.214.72.26    TCP 66  58119 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
42  5.467774    10.214.72.26    10.214.77.16    TCP 66  80 → 58119 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
43  5.467858    10.214.77.16    10.214.72.26    TCP 54  58119 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0
44  5.468186    10.214.77.16    10.214.72.26    HTTP    571 GET /tpm/lecon/fichiers/LP-2859.docx HTTP/1.1    
45  5.478248    10.214.72.26    10.214.77.16    TCP 1514    80 → 58119 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=131328 Len=1460 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
46  5.478295    10.214.72.26    10.214.77.16    TCP 56  80 → 58119 [RST, ACK] Seq=2922 Ack=518 Win=0 Len=0
47  5.478346    10.214.77.16    10.214.72.26    TCP 54  58119 → 80 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=1461 Win=65536 Len=0
```

I disabled static files compression in IIS, but it didn't help. This problem never occurs with php,css,htm,js,... files, only with documents. MIME types are correctly set-up in IIS.

I've found [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/162960/iis-aborts-request-thread-with-status-995) but unfortunatly no clear answer there.

What could lead to this issue ?